# ArcGIS Table - Split Address Column after the house number / Numeric value

Tags: arcgis

I want to split the column containing the name of the address and the house number, for example, "New Street 55A", to "New Address" and "55A" (two new columns if possible, "Address Name" and "House number").

I cannot use functions such as Left(  ) or Right(  ), as there are many addresses and all have a different number of characters (eg. London Street 555A/B, Left 42 CC, Tenere 1, Tesla Str. 522D). Basically, it would need to split after the numeric value and it would need to include letters after the number, /, or anything else.

Hope I was clear and you can help me. I must say also I am quite a beginner so a detailed answer or a full code would mean a lot.